# Equivalent of FindControl() for use with <li>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, controls

I have an `<li>` on my page. It has `runat="server"`. I can now reference this `li` directly in code-behind. However, as I do with other controls on the page, I need to find it based on a string value that should match it's ID.

As part of a loop I have:

```
var li = Page.FindControl("li" + i);
```

Ultimately wanting to change the class of the `li`. But I don't seem to have access to any attributes just as I would if I had referenced the `li` directly. What have I done wrong here? Is there another method for amending an `li`'s attributes from code-behind?

Comment: HtmlGenericControl li = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("li" + i);

Comment: @Troopers, spot on. Thanks mate. Didn't realise it was 'what to cast it as' which was the problem. Post it as the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using generic html elements on the server-side, you will get an instance of `HtmlGenericControl` when accessing the `<li>` on the server. The `HtmlGenericControl` class does not support the `Class` or `CssClass` properties as do most .NET web controls. Still you can change the class via the `Attributes` collection:

```
var li = (HtmlGenericControl) Page.FindControl("li" + i);
li.Attributes["class"] = "myCssClass";
```

---

The `Page.FindControl("li" + i)` method requires a valid **control ID**. Therefore, you need to also add an id for the `<li>` elements:

```
<li runat="server" id="li1">...</li>
```

If you are creating a dynamic list inside a repeater or list view control, however, this may not work for you, as the id's will get prefixed by the parent control. You should hook to the appropriate item created event for the repeater/list view control in order to programatically access the `<li>`.

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned that it also had an id aswell as the runat attribute. The problem was with the casting (or lack of). +1.

Answer (score 2):

Cast your control in HtmlGenericControl to add attributes

```
HtmlGenericControl li = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("li" + i);
li.Attributes["onclick"] = "return null;";
```